# Rails order not working with only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I can't find this documented anywhere but here is my problem: when I query via active record and use "only" the "order" clause is ignored. For example I have a Blog model:

```
Blog.order('id desc')
```

returns all the blogs with the highest ID first - as expected but:

```
Blog.order('id desc').only(:id)
```

returns only the id's (as expected) but the order clause is completely ignored, the smallest id comes first.

I have tested this with Ruby 1.9.3p327 and both Rails 4.0.0.beta1 and Rails 3.2.13 and I get the same results.

Is this a feature or a bug? To me it's a bug because the Rails crew were trumpeting how find_by_sql is not really needed but in this case it is:

```
Blog.find_by_sql("select id from blogs order by id desc")
```

which gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) instead of `only`.  `only` is used to override portions of the previously formed query chain.  As the [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#only) demonstrate:

```
Post.where('id > 10').limit(20).order('id desc').only(:order, :where)
```

results in:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id > 10 ORDER BY id DESC
```

This is because the `limit` modification will be ignored, since the list passed to `only` doesn't include `:limit`.

**UPDATE**

If you need an actual model object returned instead of an array of id's, use [`select`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields):

```
Blog.order('id desc').select('id')
```

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Records that come from pluck don't work with routes though - although I never asked that. I'll RTFM before posting next time. Thanks very much.

Comment: Then use `select` instead of `pluck` - it will return an object with only those fields populated.  Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I have select all over my codebase - so why tonight I'm not using it or even REMEMBERING to use it? Early night.